# DB2 Temp Tables: Not storing or not retrieving information

Tags: sql, db2, temp-tables

I'm an MSSQL guy, but I'm working on a DB2 query that needs to create a temp table, insert into it, and do stuff with it.  As a much-shortened test, I'm using the following query, which is providing the same result..

```
declare global temporary table tt_testingSyntax (id int);
insert into session.tt_testingSyntax (id) values (1);
insert into session.tt_testingSyntax (id) values (2);
insert into session.tt_testingSyntax (id) values (3);
insert into session.tt_testingSyntax (id) values (4);
select * from session.tt_testingSyntax;
```

Zero rows are returned.  Why would that be?  I've created the tablespace and verified the table is in scope throughout the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up unknowingly having access to create my own tables (i.e. for user X, I could create X.temp1). Since this query need only be run once, this works fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
declare global temporary table tt_testingSyntax (id int) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED;

insert into session.tt_testingSyntax (id) values (1);
insert into session.tt_testingSyntax (id) values (2);
insert into session.tt_testingSyntax (id) values (3);
insert into session.tt_testingSyntax (id) values (4);
select * from session.tt_testingSyntax;
```

There are two options...ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS (the default) or ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS.